# In C, linux, about kill signal and sleep() in loop

Tags: c, linux, macos, signals, kill

I run my C program on Mac OS. Part of my program is as following. This code runs well on sigint signal but can't work on sigkill signal.

```
void sigkill(int sig){
    /*some code neglected*/
    exit(0);
}
void sigint(int sig){
    flag=1;
}

void alive(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, sigint);
    signal(SIGKILL, sigkill);
    alarm(10);
    while(1){
        //printf("%d\n",flag);
        sleep(1);
        if(flag==1){
            printf("no\n");
            flag=0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have four questions:

1. At first I didn't write `sleep(1)`, It can enter the function sigint(), and change the flag value, I can see from the printf. However, no "no" output as I expected.
2. After I added sleep function, it works well. I suppose the while loop would check flag every 1 second, and output "no" if flag=1. However, it seems the "no" output everytime when I press ctrl+c. Why it don't wait for one second?
3. The question said "You should not use 'sleep()' to wait 10 seconds.  Use alarm(), coupled with a loop." I want to know how to implement this without sleep().
4. The kill command can't invoke sigkill function, how to fix this?

Comment: You can't trap `SIGKILL` — period.  You can't set a trap for `SIGKILL`.  Ditto `SIGSTOP`, incidentally.

Comment: do you know how to implement it without sleep()?

Comment: Mixing `alarm()` and `sleep()` isn't 100% reliable.  You can use `alarm()` and `pause()` — `pause()` only returns when it is interrupted and the signal handler returns.  You can use `select()` and `poll()` and platform-specific variants to do sub-second sleeps. You can use `nanosleep()` and `usleep()` to do nano-second and micro-second resolution sleeping (though the accuracy is generally not as good as the resolution).  If you look hard, there's probably a milli-second sleep somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In general, signals can only be "caught" by your application when it makes a system call into the kernel.  If you do a plain `while(1) { if (flag==1){...} }`, that will never call into the kernel.  Theoretically, when you do your outer `printf` in the `while(1)` loop, that should call into the kernel and so the signal could be caught.
2. `sleep()` is interrupted by any signal.  Check the man page for `sleep(3)`.
3. check the man page for `alarm(2)`.
4. You cannot change the signal handler for `SIGKILL` nor for `SIGSTOP`.  These signal effects are hardcoded into the kernel.  From `sigaction(2)`:

   > *signum* specifies the signal and can be any valid signal except `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`.

   The `kill` command with no arguments does not generate a `SIGKILL` signal; it generates `SIGTERM`.

Comment: I am not really understand the third answer. How to implement it without sleep?

Comment: From the man page for `alarm(2)`:  `alarm() arranges for a SIGALRM signal to be delivered to the process in seconds seconds.`