# C in mac, about signal and flag from handler in loop different behavior on different device

Tags: c, linux, macos, signals

This question is based on one question I asked yesterday:
[In C, linux, about kill signal and sleep() in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338347/in-c-linux-about-kill-signal-and-sleep-in-loop)

These code are part of my all code.

```
int flag=0;

void sigint(int sig){
    flag=1;
}


void alive(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, sigint);
    while(1){
        //printf("%d\n",out);
        //pause();
        //sleep(1);
        if(flag==1){
            printf("no\n");
            flag=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Technically what I want is when I press ctrl-c program can output "no".
Yesterday, on my Mac, I run these code and it can't output anything, then I add sleep(1), it works well as well as adding pause()
I thought that is it. In fact, this is part of assignment my professor left for us to do in our sunlab system. After I copy these code on my sunlab account (a linux platform). Run it. the output is as follow:

```
^Cno
^C
```

I can only use the sigint signal for only one time, when press ctrl-c for second time it exit, I don't know why.
My friend shows me his code, his code is just like what I attach here, have no pause or sleep, only use while(1) or for(;;). And works well on his sunlab account.

Here I mentioned three device.

My Mac: I need to use pause() or sleep(1) and can implement the function I want. Some seems correctly answer is here:[In C, linux, about kill signal and sleep() in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338347/in-c-linux-about-kill-signal-and-sleep-in-loop)

My sunlab account: exit after second ctrl-c, can output 'no' after first ctrl-c. Existence of pause() doesn't influence my result obviously

My friends sunlab account: works well. Existence of pause() doesn't influence my result obviously
Why is the difference.

Supplyment: According to my professor's word the third should be right.

Comment: Try declaring flag as volatile.  I suspect that the C compiler is pulling the flag==1 check out of the loop otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it, I didn't reset the signal(). Why nobody tell me.

```
void sigint(int sig){
    flag=1;
    signal(SIGINT, sigint);
}
```